# gdb showing different address for the same function?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

So I want to practice doing a ret2libc attack and I'm playing around with gdb on this simple program

```
// File: retlib.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("system = %p\n", system);
    char c[] = "echo 123";
    system(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Now notice this

```
Reading symbols from ./retlib...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x4004b0 <system@plt>
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ea
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/users/mickey/retlib 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004005ea in main ()
(gdb) p system
$2 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7a523a0 <__libc_system>
(gdb) c
Continuing.
system = 0x4004b0
123
[Inferior 1 (process 11593) exited normally]
```

My question is, why do I get 2 different outputs of the `system` function address. And even after I start running the program the gdb command says one thing, and printf says another. I notice that the tags for each address are different, but why is this happening? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it saying `system` is at `0x4004b0` both times?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes but the second time I type `p system` it gives me a different address.

Comment: `Reading symbols from ./retlib...(no debugging symbols found)...done.` Are you compiling with `-g` flag on?

Comment: `printf("system = %p\n", system);` is not specified way to print a _function_ address,  It is UB.  `printf("system = %p\n", (void*) system);` is marginally better.  There is no great way to certainly print a _function_ address

Comment: @DavidRanieri uhm actually no I did not add that flag for some reason... But I tried it with the `-g` flag on and same thing happened.

Comment: Technically speaking, your code is non-conforming.  A `%p` directive requires the corresponding argument to be an *object* pointer, of type `void *`, not a function pointer.  Moreover, there are no defined conversions (directly) between function pointers and object pointers, though your compiler might accept a cast as an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the program, `gdb` will give you the procedure linkage table (.plt) address, after running, the libc function address.

Comment: And which one is a valid return address for using in a return libc attack?

Comment: @DaMike See [this](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/hh-10.html#ss10.4)

Comment: @DaMike no difference, either one ends up calling `system`.